# How to installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit to Intel Joule 570x with attached USB HD?

Tags: system-installation, usb, hard-drive, intel

I've been handed an Intel Joule 570x and would like to get started.

Following the directions on this page
( https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-joule ), I can install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit into either MMIC or SDHC memory.

But I've had a few unhappy experiences using SDHC on embedded platforms.

I have a 320 GB SATA drive attached to the Joule with a SATA-to-USB adapter.  The Ubuntu installer "sees" the HD... it also sees the rest of the Joule and up pops a menu wanting to know what I want to do.

I want to put Ubuntu onto the external HD.  So I select "Something Else".

Then starts an endless cycle of "no root device selected" and wants me to correct that in the partition portion of the installer.

Unfortunately, that pop-up won't go away.

So I cancel the install and Ubuntu comes up running from the USB thumb drive (the one created per that web page).  The drive can be partitioned... but it's still stuck at that "no root device selected" pop-up.

I'm missing at least one step.  If the installer "sees" that the MMIC or SDHC memory needs partitioning and formatting, then what is the "magic sugar" to allow it to recognize that external HD?

Your time is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this GRUB2 bug before and down-graded to grub-legacy with ubuntu12(LTS). You might find it so easy to boot over USB using GRUB2 since the introduction of microcode-auto-updates in ubuntu16.04+ Have you tried booting with YUM-bootloader using Fedora or centOS7. I find the tools are more user friendly for booting linux using external-HDs. I'm also looking for that magic-sugar somewhere in the boot-flags to turn off ucode checking. I found that Bodhi-linux just ignores ucode-flag checking and boots right up into x64-bit mode. Some ubuntu-distributions won't boot at all over USB which is a bust for me cos I have no internal CDR. Have you also tried setting the BOOT_STUB firmware using a boot-utility scripts like firmware-utility-sh? See github.com/MrChromebox/scripts

Comment: The good news here is that I did solve the problem.  The bad news... well, the project died when Intel killed the Joule in June 2017 and my notes are with that employer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a few other helpful ideas about ignoring ucodes in Debian. One is to use the magic sugar flag "- dis_ucode-ldr" for AMD machines on the grub command line. The other method is to edit the USB-boot-menu options so you can control the "blacklist.conf" file. Pressing tab or (e) to edit the boot-menu then change the boot commands ro to rw and enter "init=/etc/bash" After entering the command line go over to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add the words, blacklist ucode, blacklist microcode-update, you can also blacklist firmware but then some of your wifi drivers might not load. I wouldn't recommend that but if your having a boot-strap problem you might want to consider it. Then install a new OS using the preset blacklist. This method gets around the spectra virus Debian firmware patches and ignores them. As mentioned earlier using a linux version that ignores formware patching for spectra is also a solution I use KDE-neon, & Hybirdx4 for greater firmware control. [sample of stuck firmware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDx2R.png)